# Store equations/formula in mysql db table

Tags: mysql

I want to know what is there a way for storing equations or formula in a DB column.
Below is the table where I am storing the machines details(master table). But the last column is what I am worrying.

Columns and values for the table would be

```
id,name,col1,col2,col3,col4,formula
1,mc1,546,459,1.24,3.9,(col1 * col2 * 0.0016)/(col3 * col4)
```

The formula changes for each entry in the table. Currently I am hard-coding the formula's in my program like

```
if(macid == 1) {
 // apply formula1
} else if(macid == 2) {
 // apply formula2
} .....
```

Now if any new machine gets added in the table I need to make changes int the code. So I want to store the formula in the table itself, so that I can provide UI interface to change the formula.

How can I achieve this. Plese help.

Comment: How badly do formulas vary? Can you add a few more real examples?

Comment: second machine may have, another formula like, (col1 * 2 * 0.0016)/(col 3 * col4). The problem is when i want to add a new machine to the table and user wants to enter the formula and save it for that from the UI. Now i need to add one more else if in my code.

Comment: See my answer. Dynamic SQL is the only solution I can possibly think of when you potentially have different formulas for every row

Answer (score 1):

You can try to leverage dynamic SQL.

If you need to get a calculated value for an id

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_value(IN _id INT)
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', formula, ' value FROM table1 WHERE id = ', 1)
    INTO @sql
    FROM table1
   WHERE id = 1;

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET @sql = NULL;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note:** You can of course use `OUT` parameter instead of returning the resultset if you want to.

Sample usage:

```
CALL get_value(1);
```

Sample output:

```
|           VALUE |
|-----------------|
| 82.916129032258 |
```

Here is how a procedure might look like to get all values calculated by formulas

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_values()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
    'SELECT id, ', formula, ' value FROM table1 WHERE id = ', id)
    ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
    INTO @sql
    FROM table1;

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET @sql = NULL;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```
CALL get_value(1);
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |           VALUE |
|----|-----------------|
|  1 | 82.916129032258 |
|  2 |    0.0000109375 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/557ae/1)** demo for both procedures

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?